# How to write named scope for Audits which don`t have auditables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, audit, named-scope

I am using `Audit` gem in my Ruby on Rails application. I have used polymorphic association between Audits and my `Orders`.

Now, I want to write a named scope to get only those Audits for which Order is not deleted (This is happening because Order is being deleted after creating the Audit

```
<Audit id:110,
auditable_id:4,
auditable_type:"Order",
user_id:1,
user_type:"User",
username:nil,
action:"create",
created_at:"2018-04-07 09:06:20">,
#<Audit id:49,
auditable_id:3,
auditable_type:"Order",
user_id:3,
user_type:"User",
username:nil,
action:"create",
created_at:"2018-04-06 12:28:41">
```

Now when I enter Audit.first.auditable in my console, I get nil as order corresponding to that Audit is deleted and when I enter Audit.second.auditable I get order corresponding to second Audit.

I want to filter my Audit so that Audits of the type where order is deleted is removed(like Audit.first)

Comment: `I want to write a named scope to get only those Audits for which Order is not nil `. Do you mean that order is not deleted instead of nil?

Comment: Yes, I mean order is not deleted

Comment: Should be as simple as doing an inner join here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**Audit.rb**

```
scope :with_active_orders, -> { joins(:order) }
```

Which will return `Audits` if there is at least one `Order`.

Comment: Do you mean   scope :with_active_orders, ->{joins(:orders)} ?    Then also I am getting error - ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError Exception: Can't join 'Audit' to association named 'order'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: Yes; sorry. The code above will work if you use `default_scope` but for a regular scope it should be the way you have it. The error you get depends on how you defined your association. Try `order` singular instead of `orders` plural.